# Full text feed content to Epub

Tags: epub, calibre, rss

I know calibre can grab the RSS feed content to ePub content. But sometimes (most of the time actually) the RSS feed doesn't contain a full text. I also know that there some online service which could convert them to full text feed, but they don't work quite steadily. I wonder if there some Calibre plug-in for grabbing full text from a  feed?

Answer (score 1):

In my impression, the main problem is that RSS is usually valid RSS, and the external full text isn't usually valid XHTML, so only browsers with complex parsing engines are able to make sense out of the latter. As most of web documents (websites, HTML) are seriously broken, it's quite hard to read them with a simple implementation. If you have a specific example, one might look into what the problem actually is.

Comment: for example: www.theguardian.com/books/rss

Comment: Either 1. Calibre is limited to the short RSS feed content excerpt or 2. it tries to parse the linked full text as good as possible or 3. it has some special code for Guardian articles. If case 3, how many different sites are affected by your RSS feed selection? Is a manual solution (GrabMyBooks browser plugin, dotepub.com) feasible? Do you think it could be worth the effort to develop a program which can convert Guardian articles to EPUB based on the RSS feed as input?

Comment: Actually most of the site don't provide full RSS feed (they want to improve the visit number) it would be hugely valuable if someone makes a calibre plugin to grab the RSS article. BTW, some online convert services cannot be grabbed by calibre. Thanks your time.

Comment: I won't develop a Calibre Plugin despite the fact that Calibre is freely licensed software, because its developers refuse to comply with basic technical standards, which is a huge interoperability problem in my opinion. Therefore, I would develop a standalone application for downloading the full articles, would you be fine with that or does it have to be a Calibre plugin?